# Object creation/declaration different

Tags: java, inheritance, casting

In my code

```
Public class TailList extends SList{
     ...
}
```

First question:

What is different between this two lines:

```
TailList t;
```

and

```
TailList t = new TailList();
```

And second question is:

If i write:

```
SList s = new SList();

t = (TailList) s;  // Compile-time Error
```

Why?

But, If i write:

```
t = (TailList) s;
```

I my first question state, There is no error!

Comment: Are you sure that gives compile-time error? It shouldn't.

Comment: `incompatible types error`

Comment: What is `t` declared as?

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis `t` declaration is the same as my first state, `TailList t = new TailList();`

Comment: You shouldn't get that compilation error. There's something you aren't showing us. Or it's become unclear what you're asking.

Comment: This should be a compilation error because `Public` should be `public` with a lower-case `p`...

Comment: You say `But`, but the lines are exactly the same. Rephrase your question.

Comment: Ok, solved now,Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first one declares a variable of type TailList. The second one declares a variable of type TailList, and initializes it with a new instance of TailList.

Regarding the second question: `s` is an instance of `SList`. `SList` doesn't extend `TailList`, so it **is not** a `TailList`. Casting it to `TailList` won't magically make it a `TailList`.

Comment: @JBNizet.. The casting will sure fail at runtime, but compiler shouldn't complain, which is what OP is claiming.

Comment: `t` must be declared as something else.

Comment: So, in my first line of first question `t` is `null` and in second line `t` is not `null`, correct?

Comment: It depends if t is a field, or if it's a local variable. If it's a field, it's initialized to null by default. If it's a local variable, it's uninitialized, and the compiler will force you to initialize it before using it.